# Tensor product of sheaves of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, sheaf-theory

Let X be a scheme and $Q$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. $U\subseteq X$ is open.
Is it possible to prove $Q(X)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X(X)} \mathcal{O}_X(U)=Q(U)$.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome new contributor. Right now this does not meet our standards for a good question - see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for ways to improve this. Notably, why do you think this is true (it's not always true) and what have you found in your explorations so far? Please add this sort of material in an [edit] to your post.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget an hypothesis on $Q$ ? It might help.

Comment: Yes, I forgot something. $Q$ is a quasi-coherent module.

Comment: Then look at what happens when $X$ is affine and $U$ is a princpal open.